# How to open another html file from a page with Query params

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html files

1. index.html
2. search.html

on button click I want to open search.html and pass in some query params in URL.

I did this

```
 const params = new URLSearchParams({
        sol: something,
        art: art,
        querytext: getStartedText
    }).toString();
    window.location.href = "search.html/query?" + params
```

Which open this in new tab

```
file:///Users/someone/Desktop/someProject/search.html/query?sol=Select+SME+Area&art=Select+Artifact+Types&querytext=
```

but with 404 error saying that your file couldn't be found.

If I do just this

```
    window.location.href = "search.html"
```

It opens search.html page. Any idea on how I can fix it?

Comment: You need to pass it as relative path as follows `"./search.html?" + params` and I would suggest you to go through `relative path` and `absolute path` concept. Here `/query` is not required as there's no such file `search.html/query`. Better to use relative path `./` to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

This slash at the end makes the file system think that it's a folder

```
window.location.href = "search.html/query?" + params
```

It should rather look like this:

```
window.location.href = "search.html?" + params
```

P.S.
You should consider using a local web server as working with `file` protocol isn't the best practice and can lead to unexpected behaviors when the website will be deployed.